# Firebase Function not triggering on creation of new document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have written one successful function that sends a text via twilio. This is my second attempt. I want it to send a text anytime a document is created. My function shows up in the web console and passes the error inspection. Checking the logs there are no errors or record of it firing. I suspect my path is wrong but I really don't know what the problem is.
When I create a document I use this as the path:

```
("rooms/" + myUserId + "/" + "thread")
```

Here is my index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.firestore()
const twilio = require('twilio');


const accountSid = functions.config().twilio.sid;
const authToken  = functions.config().twilio.token;

const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

const twilioNumber = '+xxxxxxxxxx'

exports.sendNewChat = 
functions.database.ref('/rooms/{myUserId}/thread')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

      const textMessageNewChat = {
    body:'New Chat From: ' + sender,
    to:'xxxxxxxxxx',
    from: twilioNumber
  }
  return client.messages.create(textMessageNewChat)

    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're interpreting the logs in the console correctly?  Try refreshing the page.

Comment: To be sure, I deleted my function and re-deployed it. I verified, in the console, the delete and subsequent re-deploy. Checking Health I get "No errors found". I created a document that I hoped would trigger the function, it did not. I verified the document was indeed created. Checking the logs I have no activity for today and no activity ever for that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is tagged as google-cloud-firestore, and in your question you mention creating documents.  So you're clearly working with Firestore here.  But your function is implemented as a Realtime Database trigger, not a Firestore trigger.  You need to build with `functions.firestore` instead of `functions.database`.  You should review the documentation for [Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to understand how to build them.

Comment: Hey buddy, how to send a text when a document is created on a collection? I cannot reach it

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same kind of problem. After spending a lot of time found that the firebase trigger function was executing after deploying it over Firebase.